# Easy API for getting historical token balances?

Tags: api, tokens, tzkt

Is there an easy API for getting historical token balances?

TzKT [has an API](https://api.tzkt.io/) and their web interface shows token balances ([example](https://tzkt.io/tz1X1Ki4rz7d6MwYvqXbYGjzouqf4WpYiquN/tokens)), so I'm surprised I can't find any "get token balance" endpoints in their API.

Thanks!